# Prediction values using Multinomial Logistic Regression in R only showing 2 of 4 predictions

Tags: r, regression, logistic, prediction, multinomial-distribution

I am new to multinomial logit regression, though I have done work with simple logistic regression.  I am attempting to build a model looking like the following:
$$
    \log(P_i/(1-P_i)) ~ X_1 + X_2 + X_3
$$
Where my dependent variable I am attempting to model for is in 4 levels: -2, 0, 3, or 7. I am running the model using the `nnet` package in `R`. While my model works, it doesn't show any prediction values of -2 or 3. I would expect this for the -2 because very little of the data resulted in -2 but a fair amount did show a 3 as the result. The model yielded a misclassification error of 34%.

**Would the reason for a binary response when I hoped for a 4-way response be something within my R code or is there an understanding of multinomial regression I am not understanding?** I know this question is very general as I would like to understand not only the math behind what is happening but also I am working in R properly. Below is my R code.

```
Drive$Points.2 <- factor(Drive$Points)

library(nnet)
model.100 <- multinom(Points.2 ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = Drive)
summary(model.100)

cm <- table(predict(model.100, Drive), Drive$Points.2)
cm
```

Comment: Take a look at my code here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230534/generating-a-propensity-score-for-multiple-treatment-using-multinomial-logistic/232919#232919 under the comment "#multinomial propensity." My sense is that yours is a data issue, not an R issue. If your dependent variable is numeric, are you certain your model needs to be multinomial?

Comment: It isn't continuous so I was suggested to try multinomial. I think my problem may be that for "3" it never has the highest probability but doesn't mean it is non-existent. I tried predict(..., type="prob") and was more satisfied with the type of results.

Comment: If you have interval data, the distance between any two adjacent measures is the same across the spectrum of measurements, then use linear regression. If you have discontinuous data, where the difference between adjacent units is not necessarily the same across the spectrum of measurements (example: Likert scale for pain), then use ordinal logistic regression. If you have named data without order, such as types of ice cream, use multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: I am not sure my data applies to any of these. Basically it is modeling for, in football, a safety (-2), and turnover/punt (0), a field goal(3), or a touchdown(7).

Comment: What I have now done is: expected.pts = (-2)*(prob. safety) + (0)(prob. of TOV/Punt) + (3)*(prob. of FG) + (7)*(prob. of TD). This makes complete sense to me, but I am curious as to what you think @Todd

Comment: What is the number of observations in your dataset? Are the observations correlated? Perhaps you a looking at the result of a possession in football? Are you interested in predicting the overall score given a sum of all the factor levels or whether a possession terminates in one of the endpoints? A table of the frequency of your results would be helpful in determining how to proceed.