# How can I weigh IPTW weight on data

Tags: r, propensity-scores, weights

[how to calculate manually propensity score weights for multinomial treatments where one of them is baseline](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388791/how-to-calculate-manually-propensity-score-weights-for-multinomial-treatments-wh)

From the above question, I wonder how I can modify the original data with weight from IPTW.

With the link, I want to weigh on 'df' with IPTW weight called 'w' in there.

And then I want to compare the mean of 'demo1' variable( before versus after).

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: IPTW doesn't modify the original data, like matching does. Any procedure done with IPTW needs to include the weights. To compare covariate means before and after weighting, use the `bal.tab()` function mentioned in the post.