# How to calculate propensity scores for multiple treatments with different predictors?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, multinomial-logit

I use propensity score matching with one control condition $d\in\{0\}$ and multiple treatment conditions $d\in\{A, B, AB\}$, where $AB$ denotes the combination of (relatively unrelated) treatments $A$ and $B$. As usual, to get the propensity scores, I used a multinomial logistic regression of $D$ on a set of predictors $X$ and did the matching (with replacement) with $D[d = 0]$ as the pool of controls for each of the treatment conditions $D[d\in\{A, B, AB\}]$.

However, the challenge in my case is that the different $D[d \neq 0]$ have slightly different predictors, and I think if I separately could use the appropriate predictors for each treatment condition $A, B,$ and $AB$, I would get a better balance with the (recycled) control group than if I use the union of the predictors for $A, B,$ and $AB$ as I currently do.

Hence, my intuition is, to obtain more accurate propensity scores for the respective treated and control, I would use separate binary logistic regressions with its corresponding appropriate predictors for each subset $D[d\in\{0, A\}]$, $D[d\in\{0,B \}]$, and $D[d\in\{0, AB\}]$, similar to how it is done in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/232919/163114), with the difference that I use different predictors.

I couldn't find any source that has done it this way, and my question is, if my approach is statistically sound and can perhaps be covered by a source. Somehow I have the suspicion of neglecting the contrasts of the treatments with each other, when I use separate models, but I currently can't think of a better idea.

Perhaps it's worth noting that I work with R, and I also couldn't find a package that allows you to define separate formulas for different treatments.

Comment: How are you sensing that predictors are different?  Certainly don't do this with p-values/stepwise regression.   Propensity scores are meant to be non-parsimonious.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks, I use the term "treatment" in a broader sense, namely for active and passive types of specific life events that can also occur together and for which there are in fact different predictors.

Comment: @FrankHarrell To address concerns as well, predictors are carefully selected by diligent hands.

Comment: This does not make much sense and is a bad idea. You need to achieve balance on all causes of the treatment and outcome, so all of them should go into the propensity score model. If a covariate affects selection into some treatment conditions but not others, including it in the models for those it doesn't will not degrade anything and will enhance the justifiability of the procedure. `WeightIt` has many methods for estimating PS weights for multi-category treatments.